# What would it take to make Craft composer based?

Tags: composer

Since there is a free edition and the plugin architecture looks relatively simple, I'd like to know if anyone has an idea of how this could work. Are there any plans for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for, but Craft does use Composer to manage its own dependencies.

If you're referring to using Composer in your plugin, it's as simple as creating your composer.json file in your plugin's root folder and running `composer update`.

Comment: I'm looking for something like the laravel installation process, e.g. composer create-project craftcms/craftcms your-project-name --prefer-dist

Comment: Ahh, I see.  We'll most likely implement that when we update to Yii 2.0 (since that's how they install as well), which would be on a major release like Craft 3.  I'll add it to the list.

Comment: @BradBell where would you recommend to place the plugins `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: above the `class MyPlugin extends BasePlugin
` ?

Comment: Your plugin's init() method probably.

Comment: I would love to hear any updates on this. This is a constant struggle with our craft sites when it comes to version control and local setup/development.

Answer (score 3):

Better late than never... **Craft 3** (released April 2018) is [fully Composer compliant](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/installation.html#step-1-download-craft)!

Comment: was very happy to see that when it was announced!